# How to subclass SWTableViewCell library programmatically? (Swipe cells)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement a SwipeCell with  [SWTableViewCell Library](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell). I want to create a subclass of `SWTableViewCell` to customize it easier. I have done it, but it does not work. I guess I am forgetting something, I mean, swipe is not working but I can see the cell.

Here is my subclass code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@interface WPUserPlanCell : SWTableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic)WPCustomLabel *tileLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic)WPCustomLabel *dateLabel;
@property (nonatomic) id <SWTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

-(void)configureCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title andDate:(NSString *)date;

@end
```

.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{    
    UITableView * table= nil;
    WPUserPlanCell *cell = (WPUserPlanCell *)self;
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
        table = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
        if(IS_OS_7_OR_LATER){
            table = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;
        }
    }
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f] title:@"Delete"];

     self = [super initWithStyle:style
                                  reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                              containingTableView:table
                               leftUtilityButtons:nil
                              rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];

    if (self) 
    {
        CGRect labelFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, titleLabelInsets);
        labelFrame.size = kLabelSize;

        tileLabel = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [tileLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [tileLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [tileLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        tileLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:tileLabel];

        labelFrame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width - kLabelSize.width;
        labelFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(labelFrame) + 15;

        dateLabel = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [dateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        [dateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [dateLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [self addSubview:dateLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) {

        Plan *plan = (Plan *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Creating Reusable Cell
        WPUserPlanCell *cell = (WPUserPlanCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlanCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            // INIT REUSABLE CELL
            cell = [[WPUserPlanCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PlanCellIdentifier] ;
            cell.delegate = self;
        }

        [cell configureCellWithTitle:plan.name andDate:plan.date];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[cell setCellHeight:_customHeight];
```

if your cell height is not default value.